# zend-fzend framework 2 cron

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2

I have application created in Zend Framework 2. I would like to run controller action as cron job. I read a lot about it but I don't know how to run it.

I did something like that. I added console route to module's `module.config.php`

```
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'cronroute' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'updateproducts',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Console',
                        'action' => 'update'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
),
```

I created Controller named `ConsoleController`

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Application\Model;
use Application\Model\Auth;

class ConsoleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $usersTable = null;

public function updateAction()    
{
    $this->getUsersTable()->cronTest();
    return false;
}


public function getUsersTable()
{
    if (!$this->usersTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->usersTable = $sm->get('Application\Model\UsersTable');
    }
    return $this->usersTable;
}
```

Inside `Auth.php`

```
public function cronTest(){
    $data = array(
        'login' =>  'cronZend'
    );
    $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
}
```

I think that everything here is OK and I tried to write something inside command line on shared server:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/****/domains/****/public_html/public/index.php updateproducts
```

and it doesn't work. When I test it writing something like that in `cron.php`

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(****);

$query = "INSERT INTO vm_user (login) VALUES ('cron')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

and in command line

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/****/domains/****/public_html/cron.php
```

it works fine. Could anyone tell me what is wrong or how to do it?

Comment: Your code looks okay at first glance. When you say "it doesn't work", what happens? Do you get an error message? If you run the command from a terminal window, what is the output?

Comment: @TimFountain OK it works fine, I did something wrong. When I change controller and action on other in `module.config.php`, it started to work. You helped me by writing "Your code looks okay at first glance". Thanks a lot.

Comment: For testing on your localhost, navigate to project directory and run your cron in consol to see errors and then configure it in shared hosting. To run from console, you need to configure php environment variables if not configured yet.